# Modal Pop Up Not being Centred

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

I am working on a simple game and I would like when the user loses for a modal pop up to Displaying information. I am able to create the modal but it does not appear in the centre of the screen despite its wrapped view being styled that way. It keeps appearing in the top left corner of the screen. I do not understand why this is.

I have tried to edit the position of the modal in the stylesheet and of I enter numbers for its left and right it does move. However, I believe this should not be needed since its container is already styled to be in the centre of the screen. Also entering those values would make it appear different on different screens

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Alert,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Modal,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Animater from './Animater';
import HscoreImage from './HscoreImage';


const AnimatedButton = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableHighlight);

export default class GameActivity extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // AsyncStorage.setItem('hscore', '1');
    this.state = {
      cscore: 0,
      hscore: 0,
      modalVisible: false,
    };
  }


  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Game",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#73C6B6"
    }
  };


  componentDidMount() {

    this.retrieveData();

  }

  getPoints = isLost => {
    if (isLost) {
      this.setState({ cscore: 0 }, () => {
        this.updatehscore()
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ cscore: this.state.cscore + 1 }, () => {
        this.updatehscore()
      });

      //console.log( 'hscore after retrieve'  + this.retrieveData() );
    }


  }; //end of getpoints

  updatehscore = () => {
    if (this.state.cscore > this.state.hscore) {

      // this.setState({ hscore: this.state.cscore });
      this.storeData(this.state.cscore);

    }
    this.retrieveData();
  }

  // create a function that saves your data asyncronously
  storeData = async score => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('hscore', score.toString());
      console.log('Saved');
      //Alert.alert('Saved')
    } catch (error) {
      // Error saving data
      console.log('Error saving score');
    }

  };

  // fetch the data back asyncronously
  retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('hscore');
      const item = JSON.parse(value);

      if (item == null) {
        this.setState({ hscore: 0 });
      } else if (item !== null) {
        // Our data is fetched successfully
        this.setState({ hscore: item });
        console.log('IF NOT NULL: ' + parseInt(item));
        return parseInt(item);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
      AsyncStorage.setItem('hscore', '0');
      console.log('Error getting score ' + error);
    }
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style = {styles.containerHscore}>
        <View style = {styles.hscoreImage}>
        <HscoreImage />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.hscore}>
          {this.state.hscore}
        </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.score}>
          {this.state.cscore}
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Animater callForPoints={this.getPoints}  currentScore = {this.state.cscore}/>


        <Modal 
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>

            <View style= {styles.modalContent}>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text> 
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
     </View>

      //<PresentationalComponent color = {[animatedStyle]} showAlert = {this.showAlert}/>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    // display: flex,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#00c4cc',
  },
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  score: {
    position: 'absolute',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 175,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    top: 45,
  },
  hscore: {
    textAlign: 'right',
    fontSize: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    top: 50,
  },
  hscoreImage: {
    alignSelf:'flex-end',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    top: 50,
  },
  containerHscore: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf:'flex-end',

  },
  modalContent: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 22,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
  },
});
```

I expect the modal to appear in the centre of the screen however it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a view inside modal first with...

```
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
```

then your centered content

for example

```
<Modal>
    <View
        style = {{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
    >
        //All view here will be centered, replace below view with your own
        <View
           style = {{
               backgroundColor: 'red',
               height: 20,
               width: 20
           }}
        />
    </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: This worked thank you. Can you explain why this had to be done. I have trouble understanding how to properly style in React Native

Comment: your welcome

@Gintak27 this because **alignItems is aligning the inside item not itself view**, the same with justifyContent.

so basically from my example i create full width and height transparent view, then all the view inside my view will be centered using alignItems and justifyContent.

mark this answer if you find this answer solve your problem :)